# Sql Server: Implementing a multi-table search

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, search

I'm trying to figure out the best way to search a number of different tables for a simple term.  I have two solutions in mind

1) Create a "Search table" with the following structure and create triggers on the tables I would like to search to enter the information into the search table

`ID       || String to check against     ||     Table      ||    TableId
    =================================================================`

2) Create a massive stored procedure to search the tables and columns I care about.

I'll be using this solution with Entity Framework for an Asp.Net MVC website, so I'm leaning towards the first solution for now.

Which solution makes more sense/is better?

Comment: Is this a one time thing or will it be in your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Full Text Search (FTS):

- Highly optimized
- Supports multiple
- languages query full text catalogs on multiple servers
- index xml type many
- more features

SQL Server FTS consists of several components:

- Gatherer
- Indexer
- Filter Manager
- Filter Daemon
- Full-Text Catalog

If you limit the number of outputs, SQL Server FTS really works well.

Comment: How complex is it to set up FTS?  Does it work nicely with ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Not complex at all, works well with ASP.NET in general. Take a look at some tutorials online.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 has a lot of overhead and duplicates the data - a big union view would be better:

```
SELECT 'Table1', Table1_ID as Table_ID, Col1 as SearchCol
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Table2', Table2_ID as Table_ID, Col3 as SearchCol
FROM Table2
etc
```

You could even make it a indexed view if you need better performance.